# Selenium - getting audio src from html using python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to use selenium to get a particular attribute from recaptcha audio-source.

however, i'm unsure of how to do so. Here is an example from https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo

1. Click on "I am not a robot"
2. Select the headphone
3. Extract the src link

   ```
   <audio id="audio-source" src="https://www.google.com:443/recaptcha/api2/payload?p=06AGdBq278w_OvG1dn_-_sgoVrqxLWcBq0IBkj2htJcsS-iTT3HtmwlhcTfBrcbQelxGI0hiep-082RypK_wZUTE-XzVbmcJ8zANM9l5O_0ka3x_7E_Hf_-vGqcRHCdRO7w2krqcgZDJSu1wj5wVyWhbDGITl55YsOs21NoX4aHk38173DPPu-Kj6T3mnqnA_3rMsdTkOUtMyl&amp;k=6Le-wvkSAAAAAPBMRTvw0Q4Muexq9bi0DJwx_mJ-" style="display: none"></audio>
   ```

I want to retrieve the src link and print it out

may I know if there is any ways for me to use selenium to do so?

---

My code so far allows me to load into recaptcha demo page -> Click on I am not a bot -> click on the audio button

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

import time

PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("http://localhost/recaptcha-v2/")
# driver.get("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo")


WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[src^='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor']")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span#recaptcha-anchor"))).click()
driver.switch_to.default_content()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[title='recaptcha challenge']")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#recaptcha-audio-button"))).click()


#This works, i can get the captcha token
# Src_URL = driver.find_element_by_id('recaptcha-token').get_attribute('value')

#This does not work, it can't locate the src
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "audio-source")))
Src_URL = driver.find_element_by_id('audio-source').get_attribute('src')
print(Src_URL)
```

Please advise thank you!

Comment: On https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo there is no headphone option.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the below code to extract `src` attribute from the `audio` tag (Change `iframe` if the `audio` tag is in another `iframe`) -

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
action = ActionChains(driver)

driver.get("YourURL")

# you can also use time.sleep(5)
wait.until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "audio-source")))
Src_URL = driver.find_element_by_id('audio-source').get_attribute('src')

print(Src_URL)
```

Comment: Hi I am receiving this no such element exception: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="audio-source"]"}

Comment: Is it possible that you can provide a URL? Moreover, you can also add some wait so that it will give time to load that particular element. I have updated my code. Please give it a try.